# htaccess redirection from https://www.subdomain to https://subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect https://www.subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com

i've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
Options  -MultiViews FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it is not affected. Pls help me to findout a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your rewrite rule is fine. put this above of any rewrite statement:

```
RewruteEngine on
```

Comment: @Nisanth I've tested your rewrite rule and it's fine! check if you have .htaccess privilege and it's not overwritten by other .htaccess files